# How to implement a QLineEdit in the column header for filtering data inside my QTreeView?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, peewee

How could I implement a QLineEdit in the column header for filtering data inside my QTreeView?

Expected Result something like this:

[image]

So far I've got this:

[image]

What I have so far is everything but the QLineEdit for the filter.
Full working code example (peewee ORM necessary):

```
import sys
import re
from peewee import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore 

COUNT_PERS_COLS = 3
col_persID, col_persLAST_NAME, col_persFIRST_NAME = range(COUNT_PERS_COLS)

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

def _human_key(key):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e))
            for i, e in enumerate(parts))

class FilterHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    filterActivated = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self._editors = []
        self._padding = 4
        self.setStretchLastSection(True)
        # self.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch) obsolete
        self.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setDefaultAlignment(
            QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        parent.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.adjustPositions)

    def setFilterBoxes(self, count):
        while self._editors:
            editor = self._editors.pop()
            editor.deleteLater()
        for index in range(count):
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.parent())
            editor.setPlaceholderText('Filter')
            editor.returnPressed.connect(self.filterActivated.emit)
            self._editors.append(editor)
        self.adjustPositions()

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super().sizeHint()
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            size.setHeight(size.height() + height + self._padding)
        return size

    def updateGeometries(self):
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, height + self._padding)
        else:
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        super().updateGeometries()
        self.adjustPositions()

    def adjustPositions(self):
        for index, editor in enumerate(self._editors):
            height = editor.sizeHint().height()
            editor.move(
                self.sectionPosition(index) - self.offset() + 2,
                height + (self._padding // 2))
            editor.resize(self.sectionSize(index), height)

    def filterText(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            return self._editors[index].text()
        return ''

    def setFilterText(self, index, text):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            self._editors[index].setText(text)

    def clearFilters(self):
        for editor in self._editors:
            editor.clear()


class HumanProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, source_left, source_right):
        data_left = source_left.data()
        data_right = source_right.data()
        if type(data_left) == type(data_right) == str:
            return _human_key(data_left) < _human_key(data_right)
        return super(HumanProxyModel, self).lessThan(source_left, source_right)


class Person(Model):
    persId = CharField()
    lastName = CharField()
    firstName = CharField() 

    class Meta:
        database = db


class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super().__init__(parent)                
        self.setupUi()
        self.setGeometry(300,200,700,500)
        self.show()

    def createPersonModel(self,parent):        
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, COUNT_PERS_COLS, parent)        
        #model.setHeaderData(col_persID, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")        
        #model.setHeaderData(col_persLAST_NAME, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Last Name")
        #model.setHeaderData(col_persFIRST_NAME, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "First Name")
        #model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels('One Two Three' .split())
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Last Name', 'First Name'])

        return model

    def addPerson(self, model, id, last_name, first_name):
        model.insertRow(0)        
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persID), id)
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persLAST_NAME), last_name)
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persFIRST_NAME), first_name)

    def handleFilterActivated(self):
        #header = self.tableView.horizontalHeader()  # QTableView()-command
        header = self.treeView.header()
        for index in range(header.count()):
            print((index, header.filterText(index)))                

    def setupUi(self):
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(0,0,700,500)
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)        
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeView.setAnimated(True)
        self.treeView.setItemsExpandable(True)

        #layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        #layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        header = FilterHeader(self.treeView)
        # self.tableView.setHorizontalHeader(header)  # QTableView()-command
        self.treeView.setHeader(header)        

        model = self.createPersonModel(self)
        self.treeView.setModel(model)

        proxy = HumanProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self.treeView.setModel(proxy)

        header.setFilterBoxes(model.columnCount())
        header.filterActivated.connect(self.handleFilterActivated)

        for rec_person in Person.select():
            self.addPerson(model, rec_person.persId, rec_person.lastName, rec_person.firstName)

if __name__ == '__main__':                         
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)         

    # create a table for our model
    db.create_tables([Person])

    # create some sample data for our model
    Person.create(persId='1001', lastName='Martin', firstName='Robert')
    Person.create(persId='1002', lastName='Smith', firstName='Brad')
    Person.create(persId='1003', lastName='Smith', firstName='Angelina')        

    window = winMain()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I already use the QSortFilterProxyModel class for sorting the result by clicking into the column header.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc, this works, but what do I have to implement at signal `handleFilterActivated` to actually DO a filtering on my QTreeVIew?

Comment: You have to use the filterActivated signal to filter using the QSortFilterProxyModel

Comment: @eyllanesc: I have no idea how to do this. :'-( Could please help out? I have updated the code to a full working example with the QTreeView. (I am willing to donate.)

Comment: 1) Okay, now your question has changed so I am going to reopen the question 2) The donation is not mandatory to help you, it is voluntary, and I never like to mention it in my discussions because it can be misinterpreted so please avoid it , if you do it great and if you do not do it too.

Comment: I have a question, what kind of filter do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the filterAcceptsRow method by implementing the filtering logic, in the following example it will be filtered using the following rules:

- Only the columns that have a different text to the vacuum are considered.
- The filtering criterion is that the text placed in the QLineEdit is contained in the corresponding row and column

```py
class HumanProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    # ...
    @property
    def filters(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_filters"):
            self._filters = []
        return self._filters

    @filters.setter
    def filters(self, filters):
        self._filters = filters
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        for i, text in self.filters:
            if 0 <= i < self.columnCount():
                ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, i, sourceParent)
                data = ix.data()
                if text not in data:
                    return False
        return True

# ...

class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def handleFilterActivated(self):
        header = self.treeView.header()
        filters = []
        for i in range(header.count()):
            text = header.filterText(i)
            if text:
                filters.append((i, text))
        proxy = self.treeView.model()
        proxy.filters = filters
```

Comment: I cannot drag the column headers anymore to re-arrange the layout of the column order. Any ideas why?